# DependencyProperty ValueChanging Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently using the following code to be notified when a `DependencyProperty`'s `Value` has changed:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor propDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(property, control.GetType());
propDescriptor.AddValueChanged(control, controlChangedHandler);
```

This works great and is quite simple, but what I really need now is to be notified when a `DependencyProperty`'s `Value` is *about to change*.  I thought there would be a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanging()` method, but it doesn't seem to exist.  Any ideas how I can create this functionality?

I need to be able to cancel the change, fire off some asynchronous backend logic, and only have the control's property *really* change if the backend logic succeeds.

Comment: I think you're confusing the IObservable interface with the ICantWaitToF##kedOver interface... Do you really think it'd be a good idea to allow OBSERVERs to suppress property changes? I don't... What's your ACTUAL problem? There might be another (clean) way of metting your requirements. Is the observable one of your classes, or somebody elses? Can you wrap it?

Comment: @corlettk Think of it as coercion instead of cancelling, then.  `DependencyProperty`s have a `CoerceValueCallback` that allow you take some action before the value is actually changed, including cancelling the change, so it's not a bad idea.  In fact it's a very useful feature, and relatively clean.  But, as far as I know, you can only add this callback when setting the `PropertyMetadata`, and I want to do it after instantiation.  And there are other ways to do what I'm trying to do, but I like the one I'm proposing the best.

Comment: Hmmm... Dunno. I'm stumped! There's nothing in DependencyPropertyDescriptor (or PropertyDescriptor) which allows you swallow the event. The only hack I can think using the published API (and this is **UGLY** with two capital ewe's) is to get-and-remove all other observers... other than that you could possibly "hack into" the existing descriptor using reflection, and hookin your coercion there... but this all sounds funky to me, and I still don't know what your actual problem/scenario is.

Comment: There's a very good reason coercion is only available to the owner of the property - all hell would break loose otherwise. Can you imagine the pain that would ensue if random code could affect the behavior of your properties? Again, what is your use case?

Comment: @Kent, yes I understand the trouble if you did coercion outside of the context of the owner, but that's why you pass the owner to the `AddValueChanged` method. Why is this so controversial?  All I want is for my IO device to determine the `DependencyProperty`'s value, rather than action from the user, since the device is the *real* source of the value.  If the user changes the value, but the IO fails, I don't want the UI to change. The IO device will send notification when the value changes. And I want it to be generic so I can use it for any `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: I want it to work like this: User changes DP's value which asynchronously sends a message to an IO device.  The IO device's value may change.  If it changes, the device will send a message to the computer with the real value, and the DP's value should reflect that value. I have lots of different controls I want to work this way, so I want it to be generic so it can work for any DP. It can't be synchronous because I need the UI to be responsive to many IO messages. I know of many ways to do what I want, but I'm asking for help with *this* way. If it's not possible I'll go with my second choice.

Comment: @Verax: would probably help to post more code then. Why not have your WPF control encapsulate the IO interaction? That way, it can simply use regular coercion. That is my point: only the owner should be affecting coercion. `AddValueChanged` is not *called* by the owner, so an `AddValueChanging` would be dangerous because anyone - owner or not - could affect the property values. It sounds to me like your design is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem at hand by implementing wrapping my IODevice in an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation and binding it to the `DependencyProperty`.

The magic is in the fact that `IODeviceWrapper.Value`'s setter doesn't actually set the value, but rather does the IO.  It turns out that when the setter is called by the `DependencyProperty` it's bound to, the change hasn't yet been committed to the `DependencyProperty`'s value.  Hence, `IODeviceWrapper.Value`'s setter gets called in by the `DependencyProperty`'s sudo-, non-existent `ValueChanging` event.

At this time, if the `DependencyProperty` reads from the `Value`'s getter it will get the old value until the IO is complete.  When the IO is complete `IODeviceWrapper.Value`'s `PropertyChanged` event gets fired, and the `DependencyProperty` then reads the new value.

My flawed design is now working flawlessly.  Here's the code in case anyone else is interested.  Ignore the naysayers.

```
public class IODeviceWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IODeviceWrapper(IODevice ioDevice)
    {
        _ioDevice = ioDevice;

        _ioDevice.ValueChanged += ValueChanged;
    }

    private IODevice _ioDevice;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void ValueChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _ioDevice.Value; }
        set
        {
            //Do ansynchronous IO
            Task task = new Task(() => _ioDevice.DoIO(value));
            task.Start();
        }
    }
}
```